# How to get a USERID from a Display Name in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot using discord.py, and in my command I need one user to input a Display Name of another user, and then the bot will reply by @tagging the second user (not the user who executed the command). I can't just get them to input a USERID as that wouldn't work with the rest of the bot command.

The display name will be server-specific.

I tried using `ctx.author.mention`, but that just refers to the command executer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should use a discord `Select` (dropdown menu) and you can make the options a group of users, such as every member in the server. Then when people click a display name, there is a user id attached and you can ping them and do much more with a user id. display names not only can change constantly, but can also be duplicated. Discord account ids are a much better method of identification

Answer (score 0):

You could loop trough every user there is on the guild by using [guild.members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.members) and check if the names match. However this could result in some problems e.g. there are multiple members with the same name on the server. It would be better to use a [User Select](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=select#discord.ui.UserSelect) or just require the user to mention the person you want to get and then access the user via [message.mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.mentions)